# Check if IEnumerable list in View Model is null in View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, if-statement, ienumerable

I just wanted to check if it's possible to check if an `IEnumerable` list is null in the view when passed from the controller via the view model. Or should I only create conditions in the controller?

My code below does not show the else condition.

Apologies if this is painfully obvious to everyone but I'm still only learning and thanks in advance for any pointers in the right direction.

My controller:

```
[Area("User")]
[Authorize]
public class TrayController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    
    public OfferTrayVM OfferTrayVM { get; set; }

    public TrayController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
        var claim = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

        OfferTrayVM = new OfferTrayVM()
        {
            ListOfferTray = _unitOfWork.OfferTray.GetAll(u => u.ApplicationUserId == claim.Value,
            includeProperties: "Trade")
        };
        
        return View(OfferTrayVM);
    }

    public IActionResult Delete(int trayId)
    {
        var tray = _unitOfWork.OfferTray.GetFirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == trayId);
        _unitOfWork.OfferTray.Remove(tray);
        _unitOfWork.Save();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "User" });
    }
}
```

My view model:

```
public class OfferTrayVM
{
    public IEnumerable<OfferTray> ListOfferTray { get; set; }
}
```

My view:

```
@model QPQ.Models.ViewModels.OfferTrayVM

<form method="post">
<br />
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header bg-dark text-light ml-0">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6  pt-2">
                    Summary Confirmation
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 text-end">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @if(Model.ListOfferTray != null)
        {
            <div class="card-body">
                @foreach (var item in Model.ListOfferTray)
                {
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 pt-md-3">
                            <h5><strong>@item.Trade.CompanyName - Have offered to trade: </strong></h5>
                            <p><small>@item.Trade.Description</small></p>
                            <hr>
                            <h5><strong>@item.Trade.CompanyName - Have requested in Return: </strong></h5>
                            <p><small>item.Trade.InReturnFor</small></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 pt-md-3">
                            <h5><strong>You are Offering in return:</strong></h5>
                            <p><small>@item.OfferInReturn</small></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 text-center row">
                            <div class="col-sm-4 text-right pt-2">
                                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-trayId="@item.Id" class="btn btn-danger">
                                    <i class="bi bi-trash-fill">Delete</i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr />
                }
            </div>
        }
        else 
        {
            <div class="card-body">
            <h3>You do not have any existing offers. Please click<a asp-action="index" asp-area="Home">here</a>to continue.</h3>
            </div>
        }

        <div class="card-footer">
            <div class="card-footer row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4 col-md-6 offset-lg-8 offset-md-6 ">
                    <a class="btn btn-success form-control">Summary</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: If you are using linq try  `Model.ListOfferTray.Count()>0`

Comment: Awe yeah, that works. Nice one! I had attempted this earlier but forgot the brackets at the end of Count.  Thank you @OssiH. :-)